# React-Navigation-V6: Getting the Title of the currently selected screen

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm using `react-navigation-v6` and `Drawer Navigator`.

```
 <Drawer.Screen
        name="Screen1"
        component={MainScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          title: "Main Screen',
        }}
      />
Drawer.Screen
        name="Screen2"
        component={SecondaryScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          title: "Secondary screen",
        }}
      />
```

What I am trying to achieve is that every time the current screen/route is changed, I want to dispatch a Redux function with the **title** of the screen I'm currently on. Something like:

```
dispatch(setReduxContent(CurrentScreen.title));
```

How can I achieve that? Meaning getting the title of the screen that's currently in focus in order to pass it to the function.

I could dispatch the function inside a `useFocusEffect()`placed in each screen component but I feel like this wouldn't be a good solution.

Comment: Do you really need a title of a screen or route name?

Comment: I think route name would also do. But I'd need a way to set it in REDUX with my dispatch function every time the route changes. Ideally not in every screen component.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `getOptions` or `getScreenOptions` method on the navigation prop.
You will have to do this manually, either pass the next screen title when you do `navigation.navigate('nextScreen', {title: 'nextScreenTitle'})` and from inside **NextScreen** you will be able to access the **title** from the **route params** or you can call the redux update store function with hardcoded title from each different screen *(which doesn't look like a good solution)*

Answer (score 1):

Use [onStateChange](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#onstatechange) callback on `NavigationContainer` to track route changes. Something like this:

```js
<NavigationContainer
...
  onStateChange={(state) => {
    console.log(state.routes[state.index].name);
  }}>
...
</NavigationContainer>
```

See [Screen tracking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-tracking/) for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a <Drawer.Navigator/> nested inside <NavigationContainer/> so this doesn't work.

Comment: This seems to work in case of nested navigators.

<NavigationContainer onStateChange={(state) => {
      const route = state?.routes[state?.index];
      const subRouteIndex = route?.state?.index;
      let subRoute;
      if (subRouteIndex !== undefined) {
        subRoute = route?.state?.routes[subRouteIndex];
        console.log(subRoute?.name)
      }
    
    }}>